# Counting number of entries in column 2 where column 1 is similar

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I am trying to count the number of entries in column 2 for the same column1 and also number of times the first entry in column2 for similar column1 occur.

For example my input TSV file is:

```
C1  NC01
    NC01
C2  NC01
    NC01
    NC02
C3  NC01
    NC02
    NC03
```

And my desired output is:

```
C1  NC01  2  2
    NC01
C2  NC01  3  2
    NC01
    NC02
C3  NC01  3  1
    NC02
    NC03
```

How can I do this using command-line?

Comment: Do you need to count col1 in col2?Can you please explain more?

Comment: col3 = col1+col2, but col4?

Answer (score 3):

Use `awk`:

```
awk '{a[NR]=$0} {if(NF!=1){y=$2;x=$0;b[x]=1;c[x]=1}else{b[x]++;if(y==$1){c[x]++}}} END{for (n in a){z=a[n];print z" "b[z]" "c[z]}}' file
```

Admittedly it isn't the simplest one, but it works for me with your given input.

**Explanation:**

- `{a[NR]=$0}`: First load all content of the file in an array called `a`.
- `if(NF!=1)`: If it's a row where we have multiple columns (more than one)...
- `{y=$2;x=$0;b[x]=1;c[x]=1}`: ... set a variable `y` to the second column value which we want to count, and a variable `x` to the whole line. Those variables are used in later iterations. Those values are also indexes in two arrays `b` and `c`, where we store the count values.
- `else{b[x]++;if(y==$1){c[x]++}}`: If it's a row with just one column, we increment the value in the `b` array. And if that column matches the second column in the primary line, which we saved in `y`, we increment that value, too.
- `END{for (n in a){z=a[n];print z" "b[z]" "c[z]}}`: At the end we loop trough the array `a` and print it's values (which is a simple dump of the files contents). We also print the counted values in the other two arrays `b` and `c`.

Output gives:

```
C1  NC01 2 2
    NC01
C2  NC01 3 2
    NC01
    NC02
C3  NC01 3 1
    NC02
    NC03
```

Comment: I'm not sure why so many of you guys are so fond of cramping everything on a single line.  Machines these days should be powerful enough to handle a few more spaces and newlines. ;)

Comment: @lcd047 Everytime little time there's a line break, something dies within me...

Comment: @lcd047; It's certainly not performance. The problem with such code is rather that it's a) not that obvious to see what it does, and b) that you don't easily see how good or badly it is actually written. Here, in SE, it's certainly better to write not only effective, but also good and legible answers.

Comment: @Janis Nearly 90 percent of my answer is the explanation, that takes the command apart and explains how it works.

Comment: @chaos; There's nothing wrong with your explanation. I was commenting on your code. - Note that the explanation does not show how good/bad it is written; for that you'd need to "beautify" the code first.

Comment: @Janis _It's certainly not performance._ - Yes, that was supposed to be ironic. I don't think whitespace made any difference in performance even on PDP-11. :)

Comment: @lcd047; Sure :-) Because of your smiley I just tried to emphasize my comment as a serious demand on the posted code; I'd really think it would be better if the poster would reformat the code in his answer. - But anyway...